# route from parent to child triger resolve on parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have routes like this (using ui-router):

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('studies', {
            url: '/studies?all&field&term&page&sort&sort_dir',
            templateUrl: 'scripts/studies/studies.template.html',
            controller: 'StudiesController',
            onExit: function exitStudies(filterQuery) {
                filterQuery.emptyQuery();
            },
            menuElement: 'studies',
            resolve: {
                attributes: function (manageAttributes, attributeDefinition, $q) {
                    console.log('resolve');
                    var promises = {
                        columnDefinitions: attributeDefinition.fillColumnsDefinitions(),
                        userColumns: manageAttributes.queryAttributes()
                    }
                    return $q.all(promises)
                        .then(function (response) {
                        var attributes = _.map(response.userColumns, function (object) {
                            return _.find(manageAttributes.getAllAttributes(), function (attribute) {
                                return attribute.name === object.name;
                            });
                        });
                        manageAttributes.setAttributes(attributes);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        ['favorites-list', 'favorites-filter', 'default-filter'].forEach(function(directive) {
            $stateProvider.state('studies.' + directive, {
                template: '<' + directive + '></' + directive + '>'
            });
        });
```

and when I navigate to child using:

favorites

the resolve console log is triggered, I don't have url in child routes because I don't want url to change when I navigate to child route.

When I added this code:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log('state: ' + fromState.name + ' -> ' + toState.name);
    });
});
```

I've got this message:

```
resolve
state:  -> studies
resolve
state: studies -> studies.favorites-list
```

Why resolve is triggered when I navigate to child route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children inherit the resolves of their parents in ui-router. This is the way it's supposed to be. You could rearrange your code to make it not a child state. Or, possibly (since I've not tried this approach), override the resolve in the child state to return null.